# Communication Between Two Computers At A Specific Datarate

Tags: c

I need help on "Two computers will communicate in serial port at 500kbps,sender will send floating point data from a file contains large data(for example 8192 nos. of data)",How this specific datarate can be obtained,please tell in c/mattlab?

thanks,

Comment: What platform are you using, and are you trying to find a way to calculate it or simulate bandwith..?

Comment: This sounds terribly much like homework.

Answer (score 1):

Just configure the UART to the specified datarate.

`man ioctl` may help.